# Confirmation please. "brass" in a headline

Tags: word-choice

I always appreciate your supports.

My question, is [**in this article,**](https://www.yahoo.com/sports/report-le-bron-james-supports-lakers-brass-as-rob-pelinka-will-remain-in-power-223016064.html)

> Report: 'Stunned' LeBron James supports Lakers brass as GM Rob Pelinka will remain in power

Would in my guess the word "brass" be equal with the definition of [**4.b of this dictionary?**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brass)

> b : persons in high positions (as in a business or the government)

I apologize in advance I have a character that I would not be convinced enough without supports by native speakers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's right.

If your friend doesn't believe then bring up the etymology (history of the word) as coming from the military, where the upper ranks usually have brass rank markers and medals. Thus, they got referred to as "brass."